# Unable to host formio code to azure using docker-compose or even with docker file

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, formio

I am trying to host the formio code available here(https://github.com/formio/formio) in azure.
I am using the docker-compose(https://github.com/formio/formio/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file for hosting.
I created a task in Azure pipelines for npm install and docker compose but I am unable to access the site. It is giving me 503 error
I even changed the ports to 80 but still the same error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]